# Change string format into date time format or separate them via Python?

Tags: python

I have a column of data which is like 20181,20182,20183,20184. I am wondering how to change them to the 2018Q1, 2018Q2 format or separate them into two columns one for years and the other for quarters.

Comment: does your last number in that numbers always lies in 1,2,3 and 4? like 20191, 20192. 20193 and 20194?

Comment: Are these numbers column name or values of a column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since years are in the foreseeable future always 4 characters long, you can simply split at the 4th character like this:

```py
s = '20181'
year, quarter = s[:4], s[4:]
# You can now use year and quarter separately or merge them back in the given format:
print(year + 'Q' + quarter)
```

Comment: If you expect to encounter years that are not 4 characters, you could use: `year, quarter = s[:-1], s[-1:]` 

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

#### Adding character

**Code Syntax**

```
def subby(list):
    lista = []
    for each in list:
        string = str(each)
        part1, part2 = string[:4], string[-1:]
        lista.append((part1+'Q'+part2))
    return lista

print(subby([20181,20182,20183,20184]))
```

**Output**

```
['2018Q1', '2018Q2', '2018Q3', '2018Q4']

[Program finished]
```

---

#### converting to dictionary

**Code Syntax**

```
def dicty(list):
    dict = {"year":[],
                "quarter": []
                }
     
    for each in list:
        string = str(each)
        dict['year'].append(int(string[:4]))
        dict['quarter'].append(int(string[-1:]))
    
    return dict

print(dicty([20181,20182,20183,20184]))
```

**Output**

```
{'year': [2018, 2018, 2018, 2018], 'quarter': [1, 2, 3, 4]}

[Program finished]
```